# Why do my 14-month-old twins cry whenever they drink milk or water?

Tags: toddler, crying, feeding, twins, drinking

Whenever we try to feed any liquid to (both of) our 14-month-old twin girls, they cry. This includes milk, water or any kind of liquid. They don't use a bottle anymore, so we are using a spoon to feed them.

We have tried various positions like: putting them on their booster seats, making them sleep on our laps. No change; they cry. However, they don't cry when they are fed solids. Is this normal among babies? We are clueless how to control them.

Any suggestions? Should we visit some kind of doctor?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE, Naranjan! It sounds unusual -- have you tried offering them liquid in a bottle or cup instead of a spoon? (I am wondering if maybe they have a hard time with the liquid sensation without also sucking, but that is TOTALLY speculation!)

Comment: Is the liquid always cold, or warm, or other temperatures?

Comment: They don't prefer cold anything, so we warm their food a little before feeding them. Same thing for milk and water. So, milk (either cow milk or formula) is always warm and water is either lukewarm or normal temp.

Comment: So a spoon is ok when your feeding them milk or water? Is a straw? That could help with the sucking, but I don't think there is enough here unless someone else is going thru it? How do the twins do with solids? With smoothies? or puree's?

Comment: @MikeofMany, we are still using a spoon. We are yet to try a straw. Until now since I asked this question, I am seeing change in their behavior. They are now more cooperative. We are putting them on their booster seats and feed the liquid using small tumblers. It's working as of now and I hope it will get better in future. For solids, we never have any problem. We started give them puree (home made) since they were 5months old and mashed rice+veg+lenthil from 9months and they are pretty good with those. We give them this food while seating on their booster seats and never had any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe they are frustrated at how little liquid they get on the spoon. In my experience, children usually go from the bottle to a cup with a sip lid, or to a straw. In both cases you get liquid far quicker than a spoon would be.